# Array of classes which implement a specific protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

Having problem calling class methods on an array of classes implementing a protocol. Swift think array contains protocols so it gives the following compile error.

Accessing member of protocol type value 'TransactionHandler.Type' is unimplemented.

**I DO NOT want to save actual instances in the array**

```
protocol TransactionHandler {
    class func canHandleTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) -> Bool
    func handleTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction)
}

class InAppPurchaseManager: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    var handlers = [TransactionHandler.Type]()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        // TransactionHandler implementations
        // handlers.append(Product1TransactionHandler.self)
        // handlers.append(Product2TransactionHandler.self)
        // handlers.append(Product3TransactionHandler.self)
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

        for transaction in transactions {

            for handler in handlers {
                 // Don't want to save instances in the array, that's waste of memory
                 // Compile errors all over the place, can be run in playground
                if handler.canHandleTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction) {
                    let handlerInstance = handler()
                    handlerInstance.handleTransaction(transaction)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you mean that every individual element needs to implement a protocol right?

Answer (score -1):

<del>Why did you named your protocol with the same name of your object TransactionHandler ?</del>

<del>1 / suffix your protocolName : **TransactionHandlerProtocol** or **TransactionHandlerDelegate**</del>

<del>2 / and your Class **TransactionHandler**</del>

Edit: Sorry, i read too fast

Edit 2 :

Remove your .Type

`var handlers = [TransactionHandler]()`

handlers array of class conform to protocol TransactionHandler

Comment: TransactionHandler is not a class it's a protocol, and that's the standard naming convention for Swift protocols (EX: Hashable, Comparable, Equatable, SequenceType, SequenceGenerator, etc)

Comment: Per my question "I DO NOT want to save actual instances in the array" that would take unnecessary memory for something that will rearely be used in the app